# Вопрос про сокращение url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Задача: сделать сокращение ссылок следующим образом(как есть -> как нужно)

```
http://localhost/mysite/basic/web/ -> http://localhost/mysite/
http://localhost/mysite/basic/web/site/about -> http://localhost/mysite/site/about
```

Пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) basic/web/$1 [L]
```

Не выходит.
Спасибо

Comment: насколько я понимаю: это брать текущий юрл и по заданным вам условиям  и формировать страницы средствами серверного языка программирования ( например php)

Answer (score 1):

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^mysite$ /mysite/basic/web [L]
RewriteRule ^mysite/site/about$ /mysite/basic/web/site/about [L]
```